# Solution for updating Assets folder

Tags: android, database, assets

i am making a quiz app and i have stored images in assets folder say assets/pictures.I retrieve images from assets folder using AssetsManager.But after i add few more images to assets folder i found that the application do not fetch updated image from assets folder unless i uninstall the previous app.I also learned that its isn't possible to update assets folder unless i uninstall old app.Am i correct? I would like to know if its possible to added assets folder images to a database and use database to retrieve images to app?Also will my new image files will be shown when i release an updated version of my app?If so how?

This is what i use to rad from assets folder

```
String[] getImagesFromAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] img_files = null;
    try {
       // img_files = getAssets().list("pictures");
        img_files = assetManager.list("pictures");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GameActivity.class
                .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return img_files;


}

void loadImage(String name) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
       System.out.println("File name => "+name);
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
         in = assetManager.open("pictures/"+name);   // if files resides inside the "Files" directory itself
      out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/" +"pictures/"+ name);
      copyFile(in, out);
      in.close();
      in = null;
      out.flush();
      out.close();
      out = null;
      Drawable d=Drawable.createFromPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/" +"pictures/" + name);
      image.setImageDrawable(d);
      //Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(in, null);
    //image.setImageDrawable(d);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }       


}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;
while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
  out.write(buffer, 0, read);
}

    }
```

Comment: You could not insert anything to Assets folder, so if you want to storage image, you should save in SDCARD

Comment: Creating a webservice will be best for your requirement.

Comment: @JackDuong i exported my files saved on assets folder to sd card folder and tried to retrieve from there.but when i update further more images to assets folder i don't find that on sd card

Comment: @Vigbyor can you tell me how to create webservice for quiz app?

Answer (score 3):

The Assets folder is a build-time resource that is read-only for the Application. Once the files are specified in the APK, they cannot be changed at run time. You will need to use local storage to work with new files that your application creates.

Comment: I understand.That's why i exported my files to Sd card location and retrieved from there but when i add new images to assets folder i don't find that to be exported.

Comment: can you give me a solution how to get it done like you said?if so will new image files that i add will be shown on app?

Comment: Your app needs to separate original (read-only) files in the Assets folder from newly created files and treat them differently. You shouldn't need to copy your assets contents to the SD card. You haven't shared any code, so we can't comment further without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: i have added code. getImagesFromAssets() i use to shuffle images

Comment: Your code doesn't explain your handling of new files nor how you work with the SD card.

Comment: within void loadImage(String name) { }

Comment: Your new code demonstrates how you mistakenly copy all of your assets into the SD card, but doesn't show a clue about the question you asked. It sounds like you need to create a web service to host your images. You will not be able to deliver new images to use from the assets folder unless you distribute a new APK. The other problem is that each time you load the images, you're re-copying them for no reason. Bottom line - you haven't really demonstrated what you're trying to do nor the problem you're encountering.