# Query related to database in Android

Tags: android, database

I am making a quiz application.I store images on assets folder to which I found that assets is a read-only so what all changes that I do later will not be shown in app ie for eg if I release app v1 with 100 images and then I add another 100 images to assets folder all I find is previously stored 100 images and not the new one.New images gets visible only after deleting old app and re installing.Some suggested that its better to add images to database and retrieve from it so that I would get updated images.Is it true?If so how to add collection of images to database and retrieve it to Image View? Also in what exact folder must I save images?If successful could I be able to find updated images too?

Comment: `all changes that i do later will not be shown in app` - Not sure where you got this info, but it is wrong. For upgrading bundled databases, take a look at [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Comment: assets folder is as a matter of fact read only, move db to sdcard or androids app specific DataFolder. Either fill it on first start, or copy db from assetsfolder to those directories

Comment: @Nachi Thanks for the reply.so can you tell me how to add images from assets folder to database/SD card and retrieve to image view.also if i add few images to assets folder on second update will it be exported to SD card?

Comment: @DanielBo Can you tell me how to get that done.ie moving images from assets to db/sd card and retrieving.Also its important that on second update all new files added to app must also be shown.I am stuck on this part

Comment: I tried few examples to move images but am unsuccessful

Comment: @DanielBo here is link on what i did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372722/solution-for-updating-assets-folder

Comment: as BitBank stated, it appears you have no idea about what you are doing and i dont have the time, nor the desire to deliver a complete solution :)

Comment: for next version of the app you might have forgot to increase the version number in the manifest file. pls check.

Comment: @DanielBo I am not a good programmer :D

Comment: @kumar I tried changing version numbers.but new images doesn't show

Comment: Sorry but I'm unable to figure it out. May be the old process is still cached in the memory that is why you are getting the old images i feel. Try putting them in drawable folder performance wise and other ways it will be easy to load. Probably it may solve your problem too. Because chances of caching the drawable folder are negligible almost zero.